# While building code in visual studios, i am facing error, .h file missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header

This is the error that i am facing :

1>c:\rcs_receiver\rcs_w2k8r2\trunk\rcsreceiver\precomp.h(22) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'shared\gendef.h': No such file or directory

and i tried searching for that fine in whole source code, but i am unable to find it. Please give me your comment on this.

Comment: You should talk to the person who wrote the code. Perhaps they made a mistake, or they did not provide full instructions on how to use the code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to include a file that doesn't exist. If you've written this code, and you don't need the file just delete line 22 from the one giving you the error (precomp.h)

If you haven't written this, ie: if it's a program or some other source files, try deleting and reinstalling, you may be missing some dependencies

Comment: This code was not written by me, i was just trying to build it.
if we build the project which contains this part of code via script in powershell it gets build without any error, the only reason why i am trying to build in VS is that i need to debug the code once it is built, so. please suggest if i am missing anything.

Comment: Kindly help me with your comment.